# Do I need to have the browser driver listening each time I execute selenium-webdriver tests locally?

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver, rspec

Do I need to have the browser driver listening each time I execute selenium-webdriver tests locally?

e.g. Do I need to double click on "geckodriver" so that it's listening on 127.0.0.1:4444 (whichever port) so that I can run my selenium-webdriver tests locally?

Note that I am using the RSpec framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the ruby bindings will start the service as needed as long as it knows where it is. (i.e. if it's in your system's path or you set it manually)

EDIT:

The bindings will look in the environment variable `path` for the geckodriver executable.

If you don't want to add it to your path, (as of v3.0.2) you can pass in the location of it with the `driver_path` argument:

```
Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox, driver_path: '/path/to/geckodriver')
```

Comment: To confirm, by "knowing where it is" you are referring to the setup? e.g.     `geckodriver = File.join(Dir.pwd, 'vendor', 'geckodriver')`

Comment: Updated answer to explain